# How can I create directory path and put my files in it while installing apk?

Tags: android, path, directory, apk, installation

How can I create a directory path and put my files in it, while installing the APK? (While installing apk; not while running the program).

Comment: You can't do anything like this until your application has launched.

Comment: what type of file you want to put in your desired directory at apk installing time?

Comment: i have 600 html files at folder, i want put the folder at external sd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to make changes while you are installing application. its only thing happens is you do it when your application is running.

For install apk on External Storage,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    android:installLocation="preferExternal"    ... >
```

and remember these,

```
When your application is installed on the external storage:

1.There is no effect on the application performance so long as the external storage is
mounted on the device. 


2.The .apk file is saved on the external storage, but all private user data, databases,
optimized .dex files, and extracted native code are saved on the internal device
memory. 

3.The unique container in which your application is stored is encrypted with a randomly
generated key that can be decrypted only by the device that originally installed it.
Thus, an application installed on an SD card works for only one device. 


4.The user can move your application to the internal storage through the system
settings.

Warning: When the user enables USB mass storage to share files with a computer or
unmounts the SD card via the system settings, the external storage is unmounted from
the device and all applications running on the external storage are immediately killed.
```

Comment: How ?
i see programs which create folder on external sd and put data files which use at program at the folder 
i can see the folder after installing apk and before running program

Comment: there are some app which have a variable set on manifest file for install on external storage then this app extract their all file or folder on sdcard that's why you see this type of app's folder on sdcard before running that program.

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    android:installLocation="preferExternal"    ... >